# Designing an algorithm given an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search, dijkstra, proof-of-correctness

Problem: given an undirected graph G, a subset H of the vertex set V, (i.e. H is a subset of V) and a starting vertex s (s is in V).

Design an algorithm that finds the lengths of the shortest paths from s to all vertices such that the paths don’t go through any intermediate vertex in H (meaning that you can end at a vertex in H but you cannot go through any vertex in H.) (If no such path exists then set the length to ∞. All edges are the same length.)

(The output of the algorithm should be an array similar to the dist array of BFS and Dijkstra’s.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it about designing an algorithm and not about programming.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I agree that this question should be closed, but not because its about designing algorithms. I'm pretty sure thats [on-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281646/1456253). Instead, I believe this to be off topic because the question is a requirements list and includes no attempt at a solution or indication of research. This puts it into the "no detail or clarity" close reason.

Comment: I don't see a question here, just a problem statement. Is this something you're trying to accomplish? Have you made an attempt and run into a problem?

Comment: @code11 The link you provide does not have any conclusion or preferred approach. The comments seem to me to say that design of an algorithm is off-topic whereas help on implementation may be on-topic.

Comment: Good catch. That was the best sounding guidance but you're right that there is no consensus there. [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286090/1456253) seems to indicate that some questions are better moved to CS. But this particular one seems more likely to belong on SO, as long as OP edits it to include a question.

Answer (score 3):

There is a straightforward way to solve this:

1. Run Dijkstra's for `V - H`, i.e. all nodes except those in `H`. Let the output be `dist`.
2. For every node `i` in `H`, the shortest path will be of length `min {dist[j] + w[i][j]}`, where `min` is applied across nodes `j` in `V-H` (can be made efficient if we have an adjacency list instead of matrix).

So basically, with Dijkstra, find the shortest paths to nodes *not* in `H`. Then, the shortest path to nodes in `H` is simply the shortest extension from a node in `V-H` to itself. (And for nodes in `H` that are not directly connected to `V-H`, they'd have ∞ as question states).

Noticed per @jrook's comment that you mentioned all edges are of same length. Then BFS can be used instead of Dijkstra's as well.

---

Another solution is running BFS on a modified version of the graph:

- Remove all edges within nodes in `H` among themselves.
- Make the edges between nodes in `V-H` and `H` directed, with the direction being from `V-H` to `H`.
- Make all other edges (i.e. those between nodes in `V-H`) directed by adding a directed edge in both directions.

In this modified and directed graph, you can apply BFS or Dijkstra to find the shortest paths of desired condition.

Comment: Why not just run SP with H added back? H can have *inner* nodes too. So we can not necessarily rely on `V - H` to calculate SPs ending in H.

Comment: Inner nodes would simply have infinity length then, as question states. We can't use them in our paths -- the question says nodes in H can only be the ending nodes of a path.

Comment: Perhaps the OP should clarify. But I don't see *inner* nodes having infinite weights. The question indeed states that : "*All edges are the same length*". So it could be the case that a node within H can be reached faster without going through `V-H` first.

Comment: The question only forbids paths going through H for destinations outside of H, but does not say anything about weights in H per se.

Comment: (1) I didn't notice "all edges are same length", then in my answer we can replace Dijkstra's with BFS. (2) The question says "...paths don’t go through any intermediate vertex in H...". I think it's pretty clear that we can only use vertices in H as the _last_ node in a path.

Comment: `min {dist[j] + w[i][j]}` seems to me to add a huge complexity penalty. you are basically running brand new BFS or SPs from every node in `V-H` to nodes inside `H` since you will need to calculate the distance from nodes in `V-H` to H's boundaries.

Comment: It's not a huge performance penalty at all. You can optimize that part easily, to the point where it'd be insignificant compared to the "step 1". I didn't go into those details as the question doesn't mention performance concerns.

Comment: For every node `i` in `H`, you will need to find `w[i][j]` for every node `j` outside `H`. At least this adds something in the order of `|V -H| * |H| * O(finding w)`.

Comment: Downvoting because I am not convinced looping over  `(V-H)*H` is either efficient or even correct in this case. There is no constraint on the edges inside H in the problem statement. I don't understand why this solution goes first through `V-H` to calculate distances of `H`.

Comment: @jrook there is a constraint on edges inside H -- "you can end at a vertex in H but you cannot go through any vertex in H". I can convince you of it's efficiency by mentioning dependency on graph's representation as adjacency matrix vs list, but I think this is unproductive at this point for this question. :)

Comment: My point is when you want to find `dist(H)` for any node inside `H`, you do NOT need to first travel somewhere inside `V-H` and then go back into `H`.  I have no idea how you propose to calculate `w[i][j]` for every `i in V-H` and `j in H` efficiently. It implies running `|V-H|*|H|` SPs which will add a huge performance penalty.

Comment: Well the starting node is inside `V-H`. It'll either jump directly to `H`, or travel through some other node(s) in `V-H`. Both cases are covered. About `w[i][j]`s -- if we have an adjacency list representation, of course we wouldn't do that. We only would check the actual edges we have between the nodes. Essentially, note that we'd need to touch every edge at most once in this approach. So you can convince yourself that it's as efficient as BFS (which depends on graph's representation).

Comment: I understand adjacency lists. Please just edit your post slightly so I can remove the downvote (it is locked in).

Comment: Done, mentioned adj list in the post.